# NLog mySQL database as target configuration

Tags: mysql, nlog

I am using Nlog with MYsql as target database.

MY configuration is as below:

```
    <target name="databaselog" type="Database" keepConnection="true" 
       useTransactions="false"
       dbProvider="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
       connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=****;User ID=****;Password=****;Connect Timeout=5;"
       commandText=" insert into logs(time_stamp,logger,message,log_level) Values(@TIME_STAMP,@LOGGER,@MESSAGE,@LOGLEVEL)">
  <parameter name="@TIME_STAMP" layout="${longdate}"/>
  <parameter name="@LOGGER" layout="${logger}"/>
  <parameter name="@MESSAGE" layout="${message}"/>
  <parameter name="@LOGLEVEL" layout="${level:uppercase=true}"/>
</target>
```

.

Still not able to insert the info or any level message in MYSql DB.

Can anyone please help me out ?

bye the I also tried command text as

```
insert into logs(time_stamp,logger,message,log_level) Values(?,?,?,?)
```

but not able to insert the data in mysql db.

Comment: Have you tried turning `<nlog internalLogToConsole="true" internalLogLevel="Debug" throwExceptions="true">`? These settings should allow you to see the NLog internal logs. I also wrote about configuring MySql database with NLog on my blog, so maybe it will help you: http://lowleveldesign.wordpress.com/2012/10/28/to-log-or-nlog/

Answer (score 3):

From NLog [docs](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-file):

> NLog is designed to swallow run-time exceptions that may result from logging. The following settings can change this behavior and/or redirect these messages.
>
> - <nlog throwExceptions="true" /> - adding the throwExceptions attribute in the config file causes NLog to stop masking exceptions and pass them to the calling application instead. This attribute is useful at deployment time to quickly locate any problems. It’s recommended to set throwExceptions to "false" as soon as the application is properly configured to run, so that any accidental logging problems won’t crash the application.
> - <nlog internalLogFile="file.txt" /> - adding internalLogFile causes NLog to write its internal debugging messages to the specified file. This includes any exceptions that may be thrown during logging.
> - <nlog internalLogLevel="Trace|Debug|Info|Warn|Error|Fatal" /> – determines the internal log level. The higher the level, the less verbose the internal log output.
> - <nlog internalLogToConsole="false|true" /> – determines whether internal logging messages are sent to the console.
> - <nlog internalLogToConsoleError="false|true" /> – determines whether internal logging messages are sent to the console error output (stderr).

Answer (score -1):

Right click on NLog configuration file. Set value to "Copy always" of property "Copy to Output Directory"